# How to select all distinct values from column A which have certain value in column B in mySQL

Tags: mysql

Introduction to the problem:
I am working on barcode tracking system which has 5 scanning stations placed along the production line starting from StationID 1 and the final station is StationID 5. Each barcode corresponds to an item that is being manufactured along the line. Some items, like the one with Barcode 95821 don't go through preprocessing and therefore are not scanned by StationID 1.

The problem: 
I am having hard time building a query that shows all barcodes that have passed StationID 2 but haven't reached StationID 3, or 4 or 5: 
List all barcodes that:
 - have passed both StationID 1 and StationID 2 (like 95813,95814,95823, 95824)
 - have passed StationID 2 only (like 95821) since it doesn't go through preprocessing

Here is an example table called scanstations:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| Barcode | StationID |   Time   |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|   95813 |         1 | 11:30:01 |
|   95814 |         1 | 11:30:05 |
|   95823 |         1 | 11:30:10 |
|   95824 |         1 | 11:30:20 |
|   95821 |         2 | 11:35:10 |
|   95813 |         2 | 11:40:01 |
|   95814 |         2 | 11:40:02 |
|   95823 |         2 | 11:30:10 |
|   95824 |         2 | 11:30:20 |
|   95813 |         3 | 11:40:01 |
|   95814 |         3 | 11:40:02 |
|   95813 |         4 | 11:45:10 |
|   95814 |         4 | 11:45:30 |
|   95813 |         5 | 11:47:20 |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

The expected result set:

```
+---------+
| Barcode |
+---------+
|   95821 |
|   95823 |
|   95824 |
+---------+
```

I use the following query to list all barcodes that have been scanned by StationID 1 and haven't been scanned by any other station.

```
SELECT 
    Barcode
FROM
    scanstations s
GROUP BY Barcode
HAVING SUM(CASE
    WHEN s.StationID = 1 THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END) = 0
```

Comment: Does your query above return any result?

Comment: *" I am working on barcode tracking system which has 5 scanning stations placed along the production line starting from StationID 1 and the final station is StationID 5"*  Can you update the example data and expected results to match that usercase better?  The example does not futher then station 3

Comment: yes, it returns only the barcodes that have StationID = 1

Comment: @RaymondNijland I fixed the data. The rightmost digit of the barcode is the item type. Barcodes with rightmost character 1 and 2 don't go through preprocessing and therefore are not scanned by StationID 1

Comment: right you are dealing with logistics, where some items are not scanned by some stations thats why some values are "missing"..  But i think your are looking for `SELECT 
    Barcode
FROM
    scanstations s
GROUP BY Barcode
HAVING 
 SUM(s.StationID >= 3) <> 1`   .. That query should list all Barcodes which didn't reach stationid 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t understand why everyone is trying to complicate, it’s not easier to use the query

```
SELECT Barcode FROM scanstations GROUP BY Barcode HAVING MAX(StationID) = 2
```

If you want to list all barcodes that have been scanned by StationID 1 and haven't been scanned by any other station, use `HAVING MAX(StationID) = 1`.

If you want to list all barcodes that have passed both StationID 1 and StationID 2, use `HAVING MAX(StationID) = 2 AND COUNT(*) = MAX(StationID)`

If you want to list all barcodes that have passed StationID 2 only, use `HAVING MAX(StationID) = 2 AND COUNT(*) < MAX(StationID)`

Answer (score 0):

Following your intention you can test scores here are your queries.

(query 1)
Shows all barcodes that have passed StationID 2 but haven't reached StationID 3, or 4 or 5:

`SELECT 
    Barcode
    ,SUM(CASE
    WHEN s.StationID = 1 THEN -99999999
    WHEN s.StationID = 2 THEN 10
    WHEN s.StationID = 3 THEN 1
    WHEN s.StationID = 4 THEN 1
    WHEN s.StationID = 5 THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END) as sumcheck 
FROM
    scanstations s
GROUP BY Barcode
HAVING sumcheck >= 10 and sumcheck <= 12`

(query 2)
List all barcodes that: - have passed both StationID 1 and StationID 2 (like 95813,95814,95823, 95824)

`SELECT 
    Barcode
    ,SUM(CASE
    WHEN s.StationID = 1 THEN 10
    WHEN s.StationID = 2 THEN 10
    WHEN s.StationID = 3 THEN -99999999
    WHEN s.StationID = 4 THEN -99999999
    WHEN s.StationID = 5 THEN -99999999
    ELSE 0 END) as sumcheck FROM
    scanstations s
GROUP BY Barcode HAVING sumcheck = 20`

(query 3)
List all barcodes that: - have passed StationID 2 only (like 95821) since it doesn't go through preprocessing

`SELECT 
    Barcode
    ,SUM(CASE
    WHEN s.StationID = 1 THEN -99999999
    WHEN s.StationID = 2 THEN 10
    WHEN s.StationID = 3 THEN -99999999
    WHEN s.StationID = 4 THEN -99999999
    WHEN s.StationID = 5 THEN -99999999
    ELSE 0 END) as sumcheck
FROM
    scanstations s
GROUP BY Barcode
HAVING sumcheck = 10`

i edited because it was not so clear.

Maybe they aren't so short as you expected but i think they're easy to understand ( if you have basis of sql) and make more sense applied to your logic. Sometimes it's not the best way trying to compress because if you do maintenance in the future you'll have to reinterpret and it's not always a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could try select the barcode that have a number of station different form the max station number eg:

```
select barcode, max(StationID), count(*)
from  scanstations 
GROUP BY barcode
having  max(StationID) <> count(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
SELECT BARCODE,S_id 
  FROM
(SELECT Barcode,GROUP_CONCAT(stationID ORDER BY stationID) S_id
   FROM scanstations s
GROUP BY Barcode) a
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(S_ID,',',1) <> 1 
   OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(S_ID,',',3),',',-1) <> 3
```

GROUP_CONCAT in subquery to return all stationID linked with the barcode:

[image]

Then on the outer query, find the first & third value of the `GROUP_CONCAT` result that doesn't match with 1 `OR` 3.

[image]

**Edit**

I will attempt to explain this part as how I understand it:

```
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(S_ID,',',1) <> 1 
   OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(S_ID,',',3),',',-1) <> 3
```

There are three components here,

1. `SUBSTRING_INDEX (ColumnName,separator,position)`

   - the column we are using is S_Id which consist of the data value as `1,2,3`
   - the separator in the data value of `1,2,3` is the comma ','
   - and the position of value separated by comma that we want to get is 1.
     Therefore, `SUBSTRING_INDEX( S_ID , ',' , 1 )` means "Get one value from the beginning of column `S_Id` separated by comma`.
   - For the second one `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(S_ID,',',3),',',-1)`, the SUBSTRING_INDEX appear twice because the first one inside `SUBSTRING_INDEX(S_ID,',',3)` returns `1,2,3` is to get three value of column `S_Id` separated by comma. Then the second SUBSTRING_INDEX is basically `SUBSTRING_INDEX('result of first SUBSTRING_INDEX', 'separate by comma' , '-1 means to take first value from the back')`.
2. `<>` symbol

   - this can be replaced with `NOT IN ()` or `!=` which all means 'not same'
3. `OR` operator

   - I don't usually use `OR` because in my previous queries I always get strange results (it turns out MySQL has some bug - using MySQL 4.1). In this test however I uses MariaDB 10.3 and so far it seems to be working fine. "The MySQL OR Condition is used to test two or more conditions where records are returned when any one of the conditions are met" ref: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/or.php .

You can add another two `OR` in the query like so:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| Barcode | StationID |  timest  |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|   95813 |         1 | 11:30:01 |
|   95814 |         1 | 11:30:05 |
|   95823 |         1 | 11:30:10 |
|   95824 |         1 | 11:30:20 |
|   95821 |         2 | 11:35:10 |
|   95813 |         2 | 11:40:01 |
|   95814 |         2 | 11:40:02 |
|   95823 |         2 | 11:30:10 |
|   95824 |         2 | 11:30:20 |
|   95813 |         3 | 11:40:01 |
|   95814 |         3 | 11:40:02 |
|   95813 |         4 | 11:40:10 |
|   95813 |         5 | 11:40:20 |
|   95814 |         4 | 11:40:30 |
+---------+-----------+----------+

SELECT BARCODE,S_id FROM
(SELECT 
    Barcode,GROUP_CONCAT(stationID ORDER BY stationID) S_id
FROM
    scanstations s
GROUP BY Barcode) a
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(S_ID,',',1) <> 1 
OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(S_ID,',',2),',',-1) <> 2
OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(S_ID,',',3),',',-1) <> 3
OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(S_ID,',',4),',',-1) <> 4
OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(S_ID,',',5),',',-1) <> 5;
```

Which return the following on my test server:

```
+---------+---------+
| BARCODE |  S_id   |
+---------+---------+
|   95814 | 1,2,3,4 |
|   95821 |       2 |
|   95823 |     1,2 |
|   95824 |     1,2 |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: I think your solution will do the job. But is it possible to give me some clarification on the last two lines of the query, since it is too complicated for my current sql knowledge? How can I also  filter StationID 4 and 5 with your query?

Comment: I know right @RaymondNijland .. Most of our servers are still using that version. Only just recently we start to use MariaDB 10.3 for three newer servers and have migrated one out of 30++ older servers.